# Lazy loading images in UICollectionView with SDWebImageManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, lazy-loading, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

In my method cellForItemAtIndexPath i have this code:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:coverURL] options:0 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
    RRRBigItemCell *cell = (RRRBigItemCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell) {
        RRRImageView *coverView = (RRRImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:COVER_TAG];
        coverView.image = image;
    }
}];
```

When i launch application and i scroll down then everything is ok. But when i scroll up than cell which were already displayed don't have loaded images (cell == nil). And if i again scroll down the problem remains for already displayed cells, only new ones have loaded images.
Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pawan is correct, that would be simplest way to implement SDWebImage. It's basically a category of UIImage, so simply use the category methods (setImageWithURL).

A couple of other points since you asked;

1. In your code, you should be setting the coverImage.image on the main thread, not in the background.
2. It's good practice to check if the Cell is visible, or there is little point in displaying the content.
3. It's good practice to create a weak reference to the Collection view when accessing the cell to avoid circular references

so your code ) might be written as follows if you were insistent on doing it the way you have it (Using the category is the best and simplest way)

```
  __weak myCollectionViewController *weakSelf = self;
  SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
  [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:coverURL] options:0 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

  } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([weakSelf.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath]) {
           RRRBigItemCell *cell =  (RRRBigItemCell *)[weakSelf.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
           RRRImageView *coverView = (RRRImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:COVER_TAG];
           coverView.image = image;
        };
     });  

 }];
```

Comment: Well i used pawan's solution even before he wrote his answer. The problem was that RRRImageView it's not just subclass of UIImageView so it was a bit more complicated to use this category but somehow i manged to do it.

I tried your solution before as well but indexPathsForVisibleItems didn't contain indexPath. Maybe it was because i didn't use main thread for it? Any idea? The code was exactly the same but without dispatch...

Comment: Apple does recommend updating the UI on the main thread, I've certainly read of instances where there is a huge delay in collectionviews and tableviews in updating the UI when on a background thread. indexPathsForVisibleItems willreturn  an array and will contain a collection of indexPaths for the visible items.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try this 
`[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];`

reference [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)