# How can I use Lazy Loading In CollectionView?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

i already used collection view controller  and lazy loading individually but i don’t have idea to use lazy loading in collection view.

right now i am working in iOS 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your code into delegate method of UICollection cellForRowAtIndexPath method on operation queue.

And, if you are doing something on ui that you have placed inside main thread, here is another example:

[Lazy loading images in UICollectionView with SDWebImageManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532237/lazy-loading-images-in-uicollectionview-with-sdwebimagemanager)

Comment: Thanks @user5113017. SDWEbImageManager is very good option for my Project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add SDWebImage to your project.
2. import `<SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` header
3. add below code at `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

   ```
   [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your image URL"]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
   ```